Buscar apenas 1 registro em tabela com registros semelhantes
Tenho duas tabelas "Produto" e dados (criada durante a query).
A tabela dados possui registro dos fornecedores que tenho, e a tabela "Produto" possui vários registros para cada fornecedor.
O que acontece é que quando eu executo a query abaixo, são retornados todos os produtos de cada fornecedor, mas o que eu preciso é que seja retornado apenas 1 registro de cada fornecedor.
Como posso fazer isso?
Resultado da pesquisa: https://i.sstatic.net/60JlWTBM.png
   select distinct
       Log_Importacao_Xml.codMsgImportacao,
       Log_Importacao_Xml.danfe,
       Log_Importacao_Xml.codProduto,
       log_importacao_xml.codfornecedor
   from EspelhoXmlNfe
      inner join Log_Importacao_Xml on Log_Importacao_Xml.danfe = EspelhoXmlNfe.infNfe
      inner join Msg_Importacao_Xml on Msg_Importacao_Xml.codMsgImportacao = Log_Importacao_Xml.codMsgImportacao
   where EspelhoXmlNfe.tpNF = 1 and (EspelhoXmlNfe.dhEmi >= :P110_DATAINI and EspelhoXmlNfe.dhEmi <= :P110_DATAFIM)
)
select 
      (select x.codmsgimportacao || ' - ' || x.msgImportacao from msg_importacao_xml x where x.codmsgimportacao = dados.codmsgimportacao) as msg_erro,
      count(dados.danfe) as valor
      
from dados
   inner join EspelhoXmlNfe on EspelhoXmlNfe.infNfe = dados.danfe
   inner join Nfe_Danfe on Nfe_Danfe.codDanfe = EspelhoXmlNfe.infNfe
   inner join Pessoa on pessoa.codPessoa = EspelhoXmlNfe.codPessoaEmit
   inner join Fornecedor on Fornecedor.codFornecedor = Pessoa.codPessoa and not Fornecedor.codRamo = 6

   inner join produto on produto.codpessoafornecedor = dados.codfornecedor
   
group by dados.codmsgimportacao

order by valor desc




Primeiramente, no seu exemplo aparenta estar faltando a cláusula With que retorna a consulta "Dados". Como a comunidade não tem noção da sua estrutura de tabelas, nem de registros, o interessante seria você criar um exemplo simulável, com criação de tabelas, inserts e consulta de exemplo.

Acredito que esta errado este join
inner join produto on produto.codpessoafornecedor = dados.codfornecedor

Deveria ser
inner join produto on produto.codpessoafornecedor = Fornecedor.codFornecedor

Abraços
